# Unable to perform docker run using Invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, docker-for-windows

i'm new to docker. I run docker "natively" from a Windows server 2016 with a Windows container, there is no intermediate VM (no docker machine) in between and no docker toolbox, so the "host" is the actual Windows Server that I run docker on.

Docker version:

PS C:> docker version
Client:
Version: 17.03.1-ee-3
API version: 1.27
Go version: go1.7.5
Git commit: 3fcee33
Built: Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
OS/Arch: windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ee-3
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.24)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3fcee33
 Built:        Thu Mar 30 19:31:22 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
 Experimental: false
PS C:>
i pulled the image from docker hub. I need to replace the files inside the docker image while running and commit changes to the image.

Lets say i have Sample.java and datafile.properties inside the docker image which i pulled from docker hub.

i want to replace that with Hello.java and data.properties[ i pulled these files from github]

how would i do that in an automated way? Any advise and some examples on this would he helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build an image automated, is to use a Dockerfile. Some information can be found in the documentation, for example; https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

If you have your `Hello.java` and `datafile.properties` in a directory, create a Dockerfile in the same directory, e.g.;

```
FROM the-base-image-on-docker-hub
RUN rm /path/to/Sample.java
COPY ./Hello.java /path/to/
COPY ./datafile.properties /path/to/
```

You can then build your image, and "tag" it as `myimage:latest` with;

```
docker image build -t myimage:latest .
```

(the period at the end (`.`) indicates; use the current directory as "build context" - the build context is uploaded to the docker daemon, and everything in it will be accessible to add to your docker image using the `COPY` or `ADD` Dockerfile instructions)

This is a very naive example, just to illustrate the concept; I suggest reading the documentation, to understand the concept, and searching for more examples.

Comment: That's right. I can do this on my local machine. I'm triggering a powershell script which will create an EC2 Windows instance, install docker and pull the image it was automated end to end. I'm using New-PSSession to enter in to my newly created instance and passing each commands through Invoke-command. I'm not able to run interactive console( docker run 474614/my_repo cmd) it comes up with an error "this is not a tty device,try to prefix winpty" . I have no idea how to make this winpty to work on Windows instance or is there any other way to make this work